# how to use Aspose to conditionally show a table and hide another table in word template?

Tags: java, aspose.words

I have a word template with two table, I want to use Aspose to show a table and hide another table in word template based on a variable in java code, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you need using IF field in your MS Word template document.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e
in the condition you can insert a merge field or a bookmark and then update the condition upon execution mail merge or setting bookmark value using Aspose.Words.
For example, see the screenshot of the template document and the code to execute mail merge using Aspose.Words.
[image]

```java
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx");
doc.getMailMerge().execute(new String[] { "test" }, new String[] { "first" });
doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx");
```

If the output format is supposed to be MS Word document, you can also call [Document.unlinkFields()](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/Document#unlinkFields()) method before saving, in this case IF field will be removed from the document and only the result will be preserved.

Comment: Could you provide the template document for downloading, thanks

Comment: sure, here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFATrZyilmhtgRPEvan-viDrvTmgdUng/view?usp=sharing Press `Alt+F9` in MS Word to see field codes.

Comment: I can use Alt + F9 to see the ...{IF "first" =....., but how you type this in Word? In past, I use Ctrl + F9 to insert mail merge field, it show {},  then I right click the {}, choose edit field >Mail Merge>MergeField, add Field name
but for your attach document, I right click and cannot choose edit field

Comment: You cannot edit the field because it has nested Mergefield and tables. To create such field, first I insert an IF field using Insert/Quick Parts/Field, then press Alt+F9 and inserted field's content (tables) and Mergefield.

Comment: thanks, the code works, but I cannot use unlinkFields(), error is "The method unlinkFields() is undefined for the type Document"

Comment: Most likely you are using some old version of Aspose.Words. I use the latest 21.8 version for testing.